# Python - Easy way to capture exception in try-except-else

Tags: python

In Python, we can use `as` to capture the exception instance in the `except` statement. However, there does not seem to have an easy way to do the same in an `else` statement after the `try`. To be more clear, see the code below.

```
try:
    raise Exception('Foo')
except ValueError as valueError:
    print(valueError)
    print('I can capture the exception instance with "as" keyword')
else:    # Cannot use "as" here
    print('Some exception other than ValueError')
    print('How can I capture the exception in order to, e.g. print its message?')
```

Any idea?

Comment: To catch everything else, don't you just catch the `Exception` base class? It's generally poor practice to catch everything though.

Comment: `else` will be executed if NO exception is thrown in the main block. You can use multiple `except` blocks to achieve what you want. In particular `except Exception:`, which is generally bad practice.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Thanks! I did not fully understand how the try-except-else work. It seems that the reason for using the `else` statement here is pretty subtle.

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    raise Exception('Foo')
except ValueError as valueError:
    print(valueError)
    print('I can capture the exception instance with "as" keyword')
except Exception as e:  
    print(e)
    print('Some exception other than ValueError')
else:
    print('no exception raised')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, @jcasner, what's double-logging? Does it mean catching too many errors than you're prepared for?

Comment: It was me not thinking it through properly - i'm going to delete my comment since it actually makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

Use multiple [`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clauses:

Either like this:

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

or clubbing exceptions together:

```
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    pass
```